# How to using widget PlainTextEdit or TextEdit for output and input text?

Tags: python, user-interface, qt

How to using widget PlainTextEdit or TextEdit for output and input text? I'm interested PyQt4.

Comment: You should be more specific in your question. Tell us what you have and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

[PlainTextEdit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qplaintextedit.html)

[TextEdit](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtextedit.html)

Comment: an answer worthy of the question, I hope

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific, but anyways, the following code will create a dialog with a TextEdit that will show the input file:

`from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui`

```
def read_file(file):
    """
    Returns all contents of file
    """
    result = ""
    with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
           result+= line
    return result

class ExampleDialog(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(Self, parent, file):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        # create main layout of the dialog
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel(self.tr("Contents of file:"))
        edit = QtGui.QPlainTextEdit(self)
        # read the file and get the content
        edit.appendPlainText(read_file(file))
        layout.addWidget(edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)

file = "hello.txt"
dialog = ExampleDialog(None, file)
dialog.exec_()
```

The above is just an example with a QDialog, but should be more than enough for you to get started.

Hope it helps!